# jQuery conflict prototype.js and jquery.js

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery and prototype libraries in same page but both are not working together. In this case either one or the other is working.

The filenames are:

- prototype.js
- jquery.js

Comment: So is it 2 jquery versions, or 2 javascript frameworks?

Comment: @ArtjomKurapov he mentions both jquery and prototype in his question.

Comment: yeah, but maybe the problem is not in prototype/jquery conflict, but in 2 jquery versions, so careful with edits :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to make jQuery relinquish it's use of the `$` variable. For example:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery.ready(function() {
    jQuery("#myElement").doSomething();  // jQuery
    $.something;  // prototype
});
```

Comment: thanks f'd.but it's code is not helpful to me .I am used many time no conflict method but not getting any proper response .So  please help or give any solid code for reduce this problem ,I am frustrated with that problem please help me ...

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

You have to use `jQuery.noConflict();`